# How can I use v-bind:style and backgroundImage with a custom protocol in url(...)?

Tags: vuejs2

I am using vue2 in a plugin environment (so no browser; it's basically running vue in a webview within a desktop app). Everything is working perfectly except using dynamic styles with a custom protocol. Since it's a plugin environment I have access to a specific folder via "plugin-data:/path/image.jpg". Using this URL with an  tag or as a static style (background-image) it works. But with v-bind:style it does not.

My markup looks like this:

```
<!-- Static (WORKING) -->
<img src="plugin-data:/actions/tpl.Layout1.jpg" height="60"/>
<div style="width: 60px; height: 60px; background-image: url(plugin-data:/actions/tpl.Layout1.jpg);"></div>

<!-- Dynamic (NOT WORKING) -->
<div v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': url1 }"></div>
<div v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': url2 }"></div>
<div v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': url3 }"></div>
```

My data looks like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    url1: 'url(plugin-data:/actions/tpl.Layout1.jpg)',
    url2: 'url("plugin-data:/actions/tpl.Layout1.jpg")',
    url3: 'url(\'plugin-data:/actions/tpl.Layout1.jpg\')'  
  }
}
```

Is this an internal resource resolving issue with vue2? Is it simply not supported or am I missing something?

(I also have access to the absolute path, but that doesn't work either...).

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: The key should be ```backgroundImage``` not ```background-image```.

Comment: @CongNguyen I have seen both. I changed it, but same problem. Images don't show. I have tried using borderColor and 'border-color' and both work. I have also set a relative URL or one starting with http://... So it has to be the protocol in the URL, right?